# determine directory path from filename in .bat

Tags: batch-file

Is it possible to determine the directory path from a file name?  For example, if my file name is 02_2020_TEST, then when I run my .bat to submit to an SFTP site, the file is place in directory //02/2020.

I have this code so far:

```
C:\Progra~2\WinSCP\winscp.com /command ^
    "option confirm off" ^
    "open sftp://username:password@sftp.site.com:22/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 BCbuwgYmCotsW0cvfLGJcwx8pSPqn9bfMwI/8VXzDPw=""" ^
    "put C:\mdi\DATA\Outbound\WP\*.*" ^
    "exit"

REM if not errorlevel 1 goto ARCHIVE
REM GOTO END

:ARCHIVE
MOVE C:\mdi\DATA\Outbound\WP\*.* C:\mdi\DATA\Outbound\WP\SENT\
:END
```

A file is to be dropped in C:\mdi\DATA\Outbound\WP... then determine that variable A is "02" and variable B is "2020", and send to folder //02/2020 at sftp site sftp.site.com.

Is this possible?  If so, how do I write this?

Comment: 1) read filename 02_2020_TESTFILE.txt, 2) get variable A (02) and variable B (2020), 3) execute send to sftp.site.com:22/02/2020 folder... does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not a programmer but I'm usually pretty good at modifiying existing code to meet my needs

Comment: 22 is the port #

Comment: yes all the same format

Answer (score 1):

If the filename is as you said and remains the same always.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*) do (
    set "filename=%%a"
    set dirname=!filename:~0,7!
    echo !filename! !dirname:_=/!
)
```

this will take all files and and process the first set of digits only, then replace underscore with forward slash.

You would need to modify the `echo` line to do the transfer though.

to give you an idea of how more or less it will work in your script, here I used cd to go to folder, but I cannot test this as I do not have WinSCP.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*) do (
    set "filename=%%a"
    set dirname=!filename:~0,7!
    C:\Progra~2\WinSCP\winscp.com /command ^
        "option confirm off" ^
        "open sftp://username:password@sftp.site.com:22/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 BCbuwgYmCotsW0cvfLGJcwx8pSPqn9bfMwI/8VXzDPw=""" ^
        "cd !dirname:_=/!" ^
        "put !filename!" ^
        "exit"
)
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm a novice... at what point in my above code do I insert this?

Comment: You have to adjust your code to go with this. You can no longer do put `*.*` because you are processing each file get its name and place it in the folders as you requested.

Comment: It would be more efficient to generate WinSCP script in the loop and execute WinSCP with the script only once at the end – To avoid repeatedly opening a connection.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks, yes. I just did not have the option to test this as I do not have WinSCP, but I will make the change hoping it will work as intended :)